# Global pipe in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make a pipe available in all the app. Acording with what I read in the Angular docs and internet, if I declare a pipe into the root module declaratios, it make's the pipe available in all the application.  I have this AppModule code:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, NavbarModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, TranslatePipe],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this for the child module:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule],
  declarations: [ NavbarMenuComponent],//<---Call the pipe in this component
})

export class NavbarModule { }
```

The pipe:

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'translate',
    pure: false
})

export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() { }

    transform(value: string, args: any[]): any {
        return value + " translated";
    }
}
```

But whe I call the pipe on the NavbarMenuComponent template it thows this error:

> 'The pipe "translate" could not be found'

If I declare the pipe in the child module declarations it works,but I need to make the pipe global, so when the app grows up, I don't need to declare this pipe(and other global pipes) in all modules. Is there a way to make the pipe global?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add the **module** that contains the pipe (and has it in `declarations: []` and `exports: []`) to `imports: [...]` of your current module, then it's available in the current module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule],
  declarations: [ TranslatePipe],
  exports:      [ TranslatePipe],
})
export class TranslateModule { }
```

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, TranslateModule],
  declarations: [ NavbarMenuComponent]
})
export class NavbarModule { }
```

Comment: I updted the code with your response, I added the pipe on the exports of the AppModule and then imported the AppModule to the 'NavBarModule' imports, but now it throws another error: 'Usepected value "undefined" imported by module "NavbarModule"'.

Comment: It would be better to create a shared feature module for the pipe, instead of importing `AppModule` in other modules. The module (in your case `AppModule` needs to export `TranslatePipe`.

Comment: I works. So finally, I must import all what I want module by module, isn't it?

Comment: Anyway is a nice idea use a common-features module istead of adding piece by piece pipes,services, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's common practice to build modules per feature not per component, directive, or pipe.

Comment: Can you add a dummy code for NavComponent inside Navbar module? Do we have to import the service there?

Comment: @sabithpocker Not sure what service you're talking about. What's the purpose of the service? Which components should share what instance(s)?

Comment: Hey Sorry for the comment, it was just a wrong question due to lack of knowledge with Angular2. Sorry for the trouble, and thank you for your time.