# Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: The pipe 'orderBy' could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my first angular 2 project and I have created a pipe transform to to sort data in my table. The project gets compiled successfully. But while running browser throws error that it could not find pipe that was created. Please excuse me if this appears so basic

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(records: Array<any>, args?: any): any {

    return records.sort(function(a, b){
      if(a[args.property] < b[args.property]){
        return -1 * args.direction;
      }
      else if( a[args.property] > b[args.property]){
        return 1 * args.direction;
      }
      else{
        return 0;
      }
    });
  };

}
```

the same is entered in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ReturnsJsonArrayService} from "./components/display-data/display-json-data.service";
import {DisplayCustomerDataComponent} from "./components/display-data/display-json-data.component";
import {Ng2PaginationModule} from 'ng2-pagination';

import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { LenderComponent } from './components/lender/lender.component';
import { PoolComponent } from './components/pool/pool.component';


import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";
import { UserLoginComponent } from './components/user-login/user-login.component';
import { FormValidationComponent } from './components/form-validation/form-validation.component';
import { SearchFilterPipe } from './components/search-filter.pipe';
import {OrderByPipe} from "./components/funding-request/orderBy.pipe";




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,DisplayCustomerDataComponent, HomeComponent,
    LenderComponent, PoolComponent, 
     PageNotFoundComponent,
    UserLoginComponent, FormValidationComponent, SearchFilterPipe, OrderByPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Ng2PaginationModule,


  ],
  providers: [ReturnsJsonArrayService,SearchFilterPipe,OrderByPipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in my html I have entered it as following

```
<tr *ngFor="let x of selectedData | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}" >
```

The component being used is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category.component.css']
})
export class CategoryComponent  {
  records: Array<any>;
  isDesc: boolean = false;
  column: string = 'CategoryName';
  direction: number;

  constructor() { }

  sort(property){
    this.isDesc = !this.isDesc;
    this.column = property;
    this.direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
  };

}
```

When the page loads on browser, it throws following error

```
zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'orderBy' could not be found ("
        </tr>
        <!--LOOP TO DISPLAY DATA-->
          <tr *ngFor="l[ERROR ->]et x of selectedData | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}" >
            <td>
        "): FundingRequestComponent@192:23 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: 
SyntaxError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'orderBy' could not be found (" </tr> <!--LOO……}
 Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'orderBy' could not be found ("
        </tr>
        <!--LOOP TO DISPLAY DATA-->
          <tr *ngFor="l[ERROR ->]et x of selectedData | orderBy: {property: column, direction: direction}" >
            <td>
```

Comment: In which component do you use pipe?

Comment: In which module did you declare `CategoryComponent`?

Comment: Sorry, attached the component in code now

Comment: I am using only one module, AppModule

Comment: I don't see `CategoryComponent`  in `declarations` array of `AppModule`

Comment: Added them now, but still getting same error.

Comment: You have to declare or import `OrderBy` pipe in @NgModule where you have declared `CategoryComponent`

Comment: but I am exporting OrderByPipe, so how can OrderBy be added

Comment: @DP3 check my updated answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global pipe in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219666/global-pipe-in-angular-2)

Comment: maybe remove orderByPipe from the providers array?

Comment: actually you have 2 pipes in the providers array, pipes should just be declared, they arent injectables.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo  I removed it from Providers and kept it in declarations but did not help

Comment: Updated my answer