# How could I define global @pipe() which would be used in all lazy loaded module in Angular without using shared module?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am using a pipe in angular to return a value. To use this pipe I need to declare this pipe in every lazy loaded module.
I am using this pipe with shared module. But I think this is not good practice to import pipemodule in every module file to use this.
Is there any best method?
Here is live example link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulattesting

Comment: Not guaranteed it's enough. If you have `@pipe` in (let's say) `PipesModule`, then importing `PipesModule` into the main module (let's call it `AppModule`) might allow all submodules to see it.

Comment: Gytis TG I think u talk about share Module.

Comment: This depends from project to project. This name also fits if your pipe is in there. I believe we used something similar as well but can't quite remember if this is all what's needed. Have you tried this? Does it work?

Comment: <div [innerHTML]="singleBlog?.body | safeHtml"></div>
I have made a pipeModule and import this in appmodule but it is not working for other module.

Comment: Try checking this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40219666/global-pipe-in-angular-2?rq=1 If it's not working, can you provide a working demo example (on stackblitz, for example)?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulattesting this is live example link.
this works with shared module.
But I wanna use better method I think this is not good practice.

Comment: What approach would be considered as a good practice? I don't know, maybe I'm also following bad practice :d

Answer (score 0):

The solution is shared module.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angulattesting
but I think this is not best approach.